# Using MVVMCross and Monotouch, can you bind to a Dialog.Section Visible property?

Tags: mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to bind the Visible property of a MVVMCross Dialog Section.

```
var refillSection = new Section() {
    new StringElement("Refill").Bind(this, "SelectedCommand OpenExternal")
}.Bind(this, "Visible IsExternal,Converter=Visibility");
root.Add(refillSection);
```

I have also tried binding the Visible of the Element directly, but does not work either.

```
var refillSection = new Section() {
    new StringElement("Refill").Bind(this, "SelectedCommand OpenExternal;Visible IsExternal,Converter=Visibility")
};
root.Add(refillSection);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have the Visibility plugin installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Visible` on the Dialog `Element`s is actually a `bool` - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Touch/Dialog/Elements/Element.cs#L71

Because of this, you don't need to use any `Visibility` converters when binding to `Visible`.

`Visible` itself was recently added to Dialog in this pull request - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/294

As you may be able to see from the discussions on that request, there was some discussion there about how to extend `Visible` so that it worked for `Section`s and even for `Root`. However, sadly I don't think those discussions reached a successful implementation - so I don't believe that the default `Section` currently works for `Visible`.

For your specific well-understood scenario for showing/hiding one of your `Section`s, then I think you **might** be able to implement this in your app by inheriting and overriding some functionality in `Section` and possibly also the `DialogViewController`/`DialogAdapter` classes. If it helps, one example of `Section` inheritance is the `BindableSection` in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/BindableElements/BindableSection.cs

Comment: I was actually using a sub class of StyledStringElement, which appears to not use Visible. I added an issue: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/403. I will take a look at hiding the sections.